# Webview control not showing this popup in Android

Tags: android, webview, popup

In My Apps, I am using webview control in apps itself to show online pages. But in it, I want to show a alert or popup they are showing a popup just like
what we are seeing at
[Sample Popup](http://samples.msdn.microsoft.com/workshop/samples/author/dhtml/refs/showModalDialog2.htm). Right now the webview control not showing this popup. Please help me to figure this out.

MainActivity.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView mWebview;
    private ProgressDialog progressBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mWebview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        WebSettings settings = mWebview.getSettings();
        settings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
        settings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebview.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
        progressBar = ProgressDialog
                .show(MainActivity.this, "", "Loading...", true);
        mWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }

            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                if (progressBar.isShowing()) {
                    progressBar.dismiss();
                }
            }

            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                    String description, String failingUrl) {
                AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                        .create();
                alert.setTitle("No Network Connection");
                alert.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                alert.setCancelable(false);
                alert.setMessage("Please Try again");
                alert.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                alert.show();
            }
        });
        mWebview.loadUrl("http://samples.msdn.microsoft.com/workshop/samples/author/dhtml/refs/showModalDialog2.htm");
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML, more precisely in fnOpen()-function, i saw:

```
window.showModalDialog("SMD_target.htm", "", sFeatures)
```

This is not a good choice, because we all "love" the IE, especially the webview does :-)

Here is a nice post why you should avoid it:
http://tjvantoll.com/2012/05/02/showmodaldialog-what-it-is-and-why-you-should-never-use-it/

If you need a popup, wrap it in AlertDialog, discussed in this post: [android: webview inside dialog or popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9172805/android-webview-inside-dialog-or-popup)

You can invoke Java-code out of the JS-code, read my answer here: [How to call javascript function from java when webview page is different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21665724/how-to-call-javascript-function-from-java-when-webview-page-is-different/21671274#21671274)

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Ok, please, tell me then what exactly your problem is.            "Right now the webview control not showing this popup." So, my conclusion was: after pushing the "Push_To_Create"-Button a popup has to appear.